# MVC4 Html formatted string in JSON result

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I have written a sample code to check an user available with the given name, if available I would like to display the text with `Red` color saying Username in use, for this I have written as follows but the text is not showing

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public JsonResult IsUserNameAvailable(string UserName)
    {
        var usrAvailable = db.tblUsers.Where(p => p.UserName == UserName).Select(img => img.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (usrAvailable == null)
        {
            return Json("Username is available", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json("<span style='color:Red;> Username in use</span>", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Can some one help me

Comment: welcome to stack. great frst question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<span style='color:Red;> Username in use</span>"
```

`style` quote not closed

AND

`return Json()` could be raplaced with `return Content()`

Comment: serializing the right way is where i see most confusion on SO MVC Q's. +1

Comment: How can I return `content` when I am using `JsonResult`

Comment: use ActionResult in you signature. Content is the correct return type.

Comment: If I used `ActionResult` I am unable to validate Remote validation and also not getting the o/p as per required

Comment: As you said I missed the close tag for `style` which works even you missed that `return Json("<span style='color:Red;'> Username in use</span>",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @Learner I wrote about `Content`, only because it's easier to read. No need in `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.